# flatness and domination

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Liu, Lemma 4.3.7 I see that giving a flat morphism $f:X\to Y$ with $Y$ irreducible scheme then for all $U\subseteq X$ (not empty), $f(U)$ dominates $Y$. I see and understand the proof. But I don't see any geometric image for that: if flatness says some 'continuity' with the fibers and irreducibility says one has one componentent why should we have domination that is almost surjectivity?

What do you think about the connexion with covering spaces $X\to Y$ which are surjectives if $Y$ is connexe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that flat morphisms are open (under mild finiteness hypotheses),
and hence $f(U)$ will be open in $Y$. And in an irreducible space, non-empty open sets are dense.

There is not that much relationship with covering spaces, except that these are also open maps.  The key intuition here is that flat maps are (at least morally,
and actually under mild finiteness hypotheses) open.

Added: I should probably have made explicit that flat maps have images that
are closed under generalization, by [going down](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going_up_and_going_down#Going_down) for flat maps.

If e.g. the morphism is furthermore a morphism of finite type b/w Noether. schemes, then the image is constructible, thus open.  (A constructible set that is closed under generalization is open.)

In any case, it is the "closed under generalization" property of the image
that implies density when the target is irreducible, and which is equivalent to openness when the morphism is suitably finite in nature.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a reference for that or an explaination if it's not too long?

Comment: Dear Gabriel, For a finite type flat morphisms of Noetherian schemes, it should follow by combining Chevalley's theorem (the image is constructible) with flatness (which gives that the image is closed under generalization, by going up (I think? I always get up and down confused) for flat maps) --- the point being that a constructible set closed under generalization is open.  If you look in the stacks project I'm sure you'll find many variations of this statement (e.g. for finitely presented flat morphisms without any Noeth. hypotheses).  Regards,

Comment: Dear @Gabriel, This is proved pretty efficiently in sections 10.5-10.6 of the book of Goertz-Wedhorn. Lemma 10.17 says that a subset of a Noetherian scheme is open if and only if it is constructible and stable under generalization, while Theorem 10.20 (Chevalley's theorem for Noetherian schemes) says that for a morphism of finite type between Noetherian schemes, the image of a constructible set is constructible. It then follows that such a morphism $f$ is open if and only if generalizations lift along $f$, which holds if $f$ is flat (by going down for flat ring maps, see

Comment: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00HW and http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00HS).